Persistence with Kogito Serverless Workflow
I have referred to this doc for adding persistence layers to ensure states and correlation context is persisted, in serverless workflow. This doc gave information on using Postgres. I wanted to check if we can use OracleDB which support JDBC, or MongoDB?

Yes, you can use OracleDB or MongoDB if you use the right add-ons. We had to remove the Oracle one due to license issues.
For Oracle, you can use this one: https://github.com/apache/incubator-kie-kogito-runtimes/tree/main/quarkus/addons/persistence/jdbc
For MongoDB, this one: https://github.com/apache/incubator-kie-kogito-runtimes/tree/main/quarkus/addons/persistence/mongodb
At the time of this writing, there's no Apache KIE release yet. So you should use snapshots from the Apache Maven repository.
